# selecting a tables column when the name is a keyword and needs to be referenced by table name

Tags: mysql

I found a table i am working in to have column names equal to mysql keywords.   Great.  That can be solved by `"` or `'`  like this example:

```
select count("count") from A;
```

will work when count is a column name as well as a keyword for Mysql.

but i have no idea how to do it when you need to leverage joins.

The following code doesn't seem to work, but you all will have an idea as to what i am trying to do.

```
select count(a."count") from A a join B b on a.id = b.id;
```

it seems that `a."count"` is not valid.  How would i go about resolving this issue so i can adjust all of my queries accordingly.

Comment: `COUNT("count")` actually does _not_ do what you intend, thought the syntax is valid. It is counting the literal string `"count"`.  You must use backticks for column or table names in MySQL:  `COUNT(\`count\`)` and `COUNT(a.\`count\`)` rather than single or double quotes.

Comment: ohhhh, let me check to confirm

Comment: Confirmed.  Thank you for the info on backticks!  That is the answer i need!

Comment: The reason you get the correct result for `COUNT("count")` is because the _string_ `"count"` is a non-null value. As a string literal, it has the same value for every row in the result set and the aggregate `COUNT()` therefore counts it. If some of the actual values of your `count` column were null, you would get the wrong result because they'd be counted with `"count"` when otherwise they wouldn't.

Comment: makes sense.  I also noticed that that correct query i needed was sum(count), which was kicking back errors until the ticks were emplaced.   Thank you @MichaelBerkowski